# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get') - mentioned everything correctly

Tags: aura, error

my component
<aura:attribute name="showConfirmDialog" type="boolean" default="false"/>

```
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showConfirmDialog}">
        <div role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Confirmation</h1>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <lightning:input type="date" label="Date" required="true" aura:id="Date"/>

                    <center><b>Are you sure you want to Submit Collection Request?</b></center>
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button name='No' label='No' onclick='{!c.handleConfirmDialogNo}'/>
                    <lightning:button variant="brand" name='Yes' label='Yes' onclick='{!c.handleConfirmDialogYes}'/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>            
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

My js

```
handleConfirmDialogYes: function(component, event, helper) {
    var Date = component.find('Date').get('v.value');
    console.log("Date"+Date);
    
}
```

I have mentioned everything correct, but still I am facing the issue, may I know if there are any trouble shooting points.

Error is: [Cannot read property 'get' of undefined]

Comment: My guess is that the code is somehow called with `showConfirmDialog` as false, so the `Date` input isn't rendered and thus cannot be found.

Comment: I cannot see an issue in code, try doing a hard refresh and verify if your changes are available in client side. Or `handleConfirmDialogYes` method is getting triggered from somewhere else too.